# jquery - filter vs not - loosing my mind x.x

Tags: jquery

I have a simple table with some columns, one of the columns has a class .day

now I want to mark rows that doesnt contain word "sob" in that column with class .day

```
$('#tableid tbody tr td').not('#tableid tbody tr td.day:contains("sob")').parent()
.css("background-color", "red");
```

somehow everything is marked in red (as not containing word "sob" in it...)

while using exactly same thing but with "filter":

```
$('#tableid tbody tr td').filter('#tableid tbody tr td.day:contains("sob")').parent()
.css("background-color", "red");
```

it marks correctly rows with sob in that particular column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because assuming the table has more than 1 column, there will be at least one column in every row which does not have the class day and does not contain `sob`.

`$('#tableid tbody tr td')` returns every td in the tbody, not just the one with the day class, so you can change it to

```
$('#tableid tbody tr td.day').not(':contains("sob")').parent().css("background-color", "red");
```

this will target only those td elements which has the class day

Comment: yes, there are like 20 columns, with ~10 classes and im "filtering" table using values from inputs connected with those columns and classes- so to show only those rows that match everything. Your fix works, i yet dont understand why filter vs not was behivng diffrently but since you gave me working example and tip - i will get it today>.> THANKS:)

Comment: @Krzysztof `filter` - Reduces the set of matched elements and `not` - removes elements from the set of matched elements. You can try Arun's code with changing `not` to 'filter' and will see the diffences.